Generate array based on two others
I have two arrays:
[["106373", "106374", "106375", "106376"], ["106377", "106378", "220183", "220184"], ["220185", "220186", "220187", "220188"], ["220189", "220190", "106379"]]

[["106373", 15],
 ["106374", 16],
 ["106375", 17],
 ["106376", 18],
 ["106377", 19],
 ["106378", 20],
 ["106379", 77],
 ["220183", 38],
 ["220184", 39],
 ["220185", 40],
 ["220186", 41],
 ["220187", 42],
 ["220188", 43],
 ["220189", 44],
 ["220190", 76]]

What I need is return an array equal to the first but with the items replaced by the number in the second with the same value. Expected result:
[[15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 76, 77]]

I tried a lot of loops with methods like select and map but with no success.

Please add the last approach you tried to the question.

"I tried a lot of loops with methods like select and map but with no success" – include your code next time. Understanding why your approach didn't work can be more valuable than having someone else write it from scratch.

First, convert the second list into a Hash to make lookups faster. Then call map on the original list twice and look up the value:
lists = [["106373", "106374", "106375", "106376"], ["106377", "106378", "220183", "220184"], ["220185", "220186", "220187", "220188"], ["220189", "220190", "106379"]]

mapping = [
  ["106373", 15],
  ["106374", 16],
  ["106375", 17],
  ["106376", 18],
  ["106377", 19],
  ["106378", 20],
  ["106379", 77],
  ["220183", 38],
  ["220184", 39],
  ["220185", 40],
  ["220186", 41],
  ["220187", 42],
  ["220188", 43],
  ["220189", 44],
  ["220190", 76]
]

hash = mapping.to_h

p lists.map { |list| list.map { hash[_1] } }

Output:
[[15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 76, 77]]

Note: If a value doesn't exist in the mapping, you'll get nil in the resulting output.

That was perfect. In my case, there will always be the corresponding value, so no nils. Thank you very much.

lists.map { |list| list.map { hash[_1] } } could be converted to lists.map { |list| hash.values_at(*list) }

You can also use assoc to achieve the same result without converting mapping to hash (keeping in mind that there are always corresponding values in mapping):
lists = [["106373", "106374", "106375", "106376"], ["106377", "106378", "220183", "220184"], ["220185", "220186", "220187", "220188"], ["220189", "220190", "106379"]]
mapping = [["106373", 15], ["106374", 16], ["106375", 17], ["106376", 18], ["106377", 19], ["106378", 20], ["106379", 77], ["220183", 38],["220184", 39], ["220185", 40], ["220186", 41], ["220187", 42], ["220188", 43], ["220189", 44], ["220190", 76]]

lists.map { |list| list.map { mapping.assoc(_1)[1]  }  }
# => [[15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 76, 77]]

